# create storage link in lumen

Tags: laravel, lumen

I saw some questions about, people say to run this command

`ln -s ../storage/app/public public/storage`

And it works, it copies the folder, but it doesn't update when another file/image is added to the storage folder, you have to run the command again to be able to get it.

How do I make it equal to Laravel, that the public folder is always 'copying' the storage files?

Version: "laravel/lumen-framework": "^8.3.1",
"league/flysystem": "1.1"

Comment: I don't really understand the problem. With the Linux command `ln -s`, you can create a so-called symbolic link. This means that you can connect multiple otherwise non-existent paths to a single path. To continue with the example: you want to be able to access the `./storage/app/public` path from `./public/storage` as well. In this case, Linux creates a file that corresponds to a symbolic link named `storage` in the `./public` directory, and it will know that when you ask for the file `./public/storage/test.txt`, it will return the file `./storage/app/public/test.txt` to you.

Comment: [Help for Linux symbolic link commands.](https://www.grepper.com/answers/645810/centos+symlink+folder?ucard=1) Perhaps this can help you. --- Symbolic links only need to be created once. Linux remembers them until they are deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Lumen/Laravel way to create symlink:

```php
app()->make('files')
    ->link(storage_path('app/public'), rtrim(app()->basePath('public/storage/'), '/'));
```

*updated.* Create a command example:

```
php artisan make:command FilesLinkCommand
```

then next file will be created: `app/Console/Commands/FilesLinkCommand.php`

Open it and change some thingth:

1. better command signature:
   `protected $signature = 'files:link';`
2. command description: `protected $description = 'Create symlink link for files';`
3. command code, update method handle():

```php
public function handle(): void
{
    // check if exists public/storage
    if ( file_exists(app()->basePath('public/storage/')) ) {
        $this->error("Symlink exists!");
        exit(0);
    }
    // check if exists storage/app/public
    if ( !file_exists(storage_path('app/public')) ) {
        $this->error("Storage folder [app/public] not exists!");
        exit(0);
    }
    // actually, we can create folders if not exists
    // using mkdir() php function, or File::makeDirectory()
    // but the second one still uses mkdir() behind the scene

    app()->make('files')
        ->link(storage_path('app/public'), rtrim(app()->basePath('public/storage/'), '/'));
    $this->info("Symlink created!");
}
```

That's all we need!

Using: `php artisan files:link`

If command run first time you will see message `Symlink created`, next time it will be changed to `Symlink exists!`

---

php function [symlink()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.symlink.php) can do the same

Answer (score -1):

First, make sure the `storage/app/public` folder exists. if not, please create a new one.

Then run:

```bash
ln -sfv ~/path/to/storage/app/public ~/path/to/public/storage
```

Then, move files at `storage/app/public`

Now you should be able to access assets like this:

```
http://localhost:8000/storage/logo.png
```

`